# How to install auto-complete via package system?

Tags: package, auto-complete-mode

I'm trying to get work `auto-complete`. I've installed the package from MELPA successfully. However, it just does not work. When I enable `auto-complete-mode` the mode seems to be active (I see `AC` in the list of minor modes), but there is no pop-up window displaying completions when I enter some text.

I thought that it should work out-of-box, but may be it's not the case. I cannot find instructions how to configure the package installed via package manager, not manually. What actions should I undertake?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Package installation isn't intended to *enable* packages. Rather, installation makes code *available* for use. So some config is generally required for non-trivial packages.

Fortunately, `auto-complete` comes with `auto-complete-config`, so you might try initialization code like the following:

```
(require 'auto-complete-config)
(global-auto-complete-mode t)
(set-default 'ac-sources
             '(ac-source-imenu
               ac-source-dictionary
               ac-source-words-in-buffer
               ac-source-words-in-same-mode-buffers
               ac-source-words-in-all-buffer))
```

Comment: Is it normal that I should wait 3-4 seconds for the menu? Can I set time of this delay or maybe my computer is really slow ;-)

Comment: This has little to do with the initial question, please open a new one for this issue.

Comment: @Mark Try `M-x customize-group RET auto-complete RET` and have a read through [the manual](http://cx4a.org/software/auto-complete/manual.html).

Comment: What is principal difference between `(set-default 'ac-sources ...)` and `(ac-config-default)`?

Comment: Haven't looked at the latter, but it probably sets up a slightly different list of sources, so you could probably use whichever you prefer.